# .NET EF Core Plus BulkInsert takes forever

Tags: .net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, azure-sql-database, bulkinsert

I have a WebApi where I try to insert, with AppDbContext.BulkInsertAsync(...) from EF Core Plus (https://www.nuget.org/packages/Z.EntityFramework.Plus.EFCore/), 15.000+ records in my database.

Unfortunately it just takes forever, also when I try do insert only 10 records, it takes 15-20 seconds to do so:

`AppDbContext.BulkInsert(myEntities.Take(10));`

But I need to achieve the following:

```
// Store the actual Trucks
List<MyEntity> myEntities = new List<MyEntity>(); // <-- Contains more than 15.000 objects
AppDbContext.BulkInsert(newTruckCosts); // <-- This takes forever...
```

*MyEntity has 19 properties, with 5 Foreign Keys to other entities.*

I really tried a lot, but I am really stuck here, especially for 15.000+ records it just takes forever.

Could it also be that it takes so long, because my entity has a few Foreign Keys, referencing other entities in my DB ?

Also, don't know if this matters, I am using a SQL Database in Azure (Basic Tier), .NET Core and EntityFramework Core.

Comment: I'm the owner of this library, if you wish we review and try to find why it currently takes time, please provide us a runnable project here: info@zzzprojects.com, it's currently impossible to find out why this is happening with the current information since as you would have expected, it should be a lot faster.

Comment: @JonathanMagnan Would you mind setting up a conference call via Teams/Skype?

Comment: Have a look at the Azure SQL performance diagnostics.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-query-performance

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft I did and I can see the query, but how should this help me ?

Comment: Does the query take a lot of resources?  What are the wait stats?  Does scaling up the database help?  What does "forever" really mean here?  What about 100 rows?  1000?

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft So, indeed the SQL Server is at 100% at that time, but also locally on a Postgresql server it takes forever.

Comment: Can you test with just SqlBulkCopy or BCP? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft So basically I upload my CSV file which is being parsed (quickly) and stores it in a list, that list is being inserted at the end. When I use this CSV file it takes forever. Yesterday I copied that CSV file and changed the real data to test data and suddenly it worked within a few seconds.

Something wrong with that CSV file maybe ?

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft Same behaviour with SqlBulkCopy ... just tried it

Comment: I changed in Azure from Basic Tier to Standard Tier and now i insert 15.000+ records in 18 seconds more or less. Is that okay?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So a major improvement was achieved by upgrading the Azure SQL Database from a Basic Tier to a Standard S1 Tier.

With Basic Tier it just took forever and now with a Standard S1 Tier it takes more or less 15 seconds, which is totally fine in my case.